# Google analytics record first click

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, click, event-tracking

I went through GA documentation but I didn't really manage to find the answer I wanted.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide
Is there a tag or event that enables recording every first clicks of each unique visit on a page/session?

I am assuming this would be tracking the first clicks of all the unique events on a page.

Comment: Did you try googling that? https://moz.com/blog/first-touch-tracking-in-google-analytics, https://www.distilled.net/blog/seo/first-touch-tracking-in-google-analytics/

Comment: Yes, but I was unsuccessful unfortunately.
It would be the equivalent of 'first clicks' software solutions on the market I think.

Comment: The linked script does not work with the current version of Google Analytics (which does not have custom vars).

Comment: The "first clicks of each unique visit" would be the landing page - do you mean the first click of the _visitor_  (i.e. the first click a specific person ever made on your website) ?

Comment: Hi Eike,
Thanks for the comment.
Yes, this is exactly what I mean.

Comment: I think this isn't easily available out of the box.  I think you may have to implement some logic (in GTM or similar) that when a GA event is fired, you also write to a cookie if it doesn't yet exist, then read the value from that cookie.

Answer (score -1):

Copy-paste from https://moz.com/blog/first-touch-tracking-in-google-analytics

> Include following code anywhere above the Google Analytics code script
>   in your page code:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript"
> src="http://attributiontrackingga.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distilled.FirstTouch.js">
> </script>
> ```
>
> Move your GA code above any Website Optimizer code or anything from
>   Google that might write a visitor (__utma) cookie and look for:
>
> ```
> var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXXXX-X");
>
> pageTracker._trackPageview();
> ```
>
> In between those two lines, you want to put the following line:
>
> ```
> distilledFirstTouch(pageTracker);
> ```